# Bourbon Neat: Invalid CSS after "max-width ": expected media query list, was "80em 12"

Tags: sass, bourbon

For my Jekyll project I have this Sass code:

```
@import "neat/neat-helpers";
$max-width: em(1280);

/* Screen sizes for media query mixin */

$micro-only: new-breakpoint(min-width em(240) max-width em(480) 12);
$medium: new-breakpoint(min-width em(768) 12);
$large: new-breakpoint(min-width em(1280) 12);
```

And running `jekyll build` i get the error:

```
Conversion error: Jekyll::Converters::Scss encountered an error converting 'assets/css/main.scss'.
Conversion error: Invalid CSS after "max-width ": expected media query list, was "80em 12"
```

Comment: does `assets/css/main.scss` file exists?

Answer (score 1):

Reading the [bourbon new-breakpoint doc](http://thoughtbot.github.io/neat-docs/latest/#new-breakpoint) and [some examples here](http://devin-clark.com/getting-started-with-bourbon/), it seems that you can do :

```
$micro-only: new-breakpoint(min-width em(240) max-width em(480), 12);
```